# linear layout inside another linear layout programmatically

Tags: dynamic, android-linearlayout

I want to implement a UI for designing dynamic forms. I want a structure like this:

```
-------------------- - ------------------- - ---------
|  OuterLinearLayout  
|       ----------  ----------
|       |InnerLinearLayout1    |   |
|       |                      |
|        ---------- - ---------
| 
|       ---------- - ---------
|       |InnerLinearLayout2   |
|       |                     |
         ---------- - ---------




|       ---------- - ---------
|       |InnerLinearLayout-n   |
|       |                      |
         ---------- - ---------

|
|
|---------- - ------------------- - ---------
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I do not understand your question, you already decided a layout, what are you asking specifically?

Comment: @Bonatti I have LinearLayout already defined in Xml but the inner layout I want to add at runtime using for loop.